# How to send a message to all members who have a role (discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm coding a bot using discord.js.
I would like to send a `<message>` to all members who have  `<role>` when I write :

`/a <role> <message>`

in a channel.

How can I do this ?

Thank you for your help ! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possibility how it could work:

```
const args = message.content.split(" ");
const roleArgs = args.slice(0, 1);
const messageArgs = args.slice(1)

const role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name.toLowerCase() === roleArgs.join(" ").toLowerCase())
if (!role) return message.reply('There is not such a role!');

for (let i = 0; i < message.guild.members.size; i++) {
    if (message.guild.members[i].roles.has(role.id)) {
        message.guild.members[i].user.send(messageArgs.join(" "))
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind this is a little bit against discord's API so if you are going to do this I wouldn't make it a public bot

Comment: Or add a timeout between sending because someone could easily just make you send 1000s of messages at once