# discord.js || dm users with certain role

Tags: javascript, discord

I want to add a function to my bot that would dm every person with a certain role, for ex.

&dmrole [role] [message]

I have no idea how to do that

**Thanks for your help!**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send a message to all members who have a role (discord.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261942/how-to-send-a-message-to-all-members-who-have-a-role-discord-js)

Comment: tried that and unfortunately it doesn’t help me

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: Also, you should use the `discord.js` tag for `discord.js` questions, not `discord`

Comment: @wex Your question is not tied to a specific coding problem and thus not suited for StackOverflow. Your question is very broad. Maybe you need to take other sources of help into consideration.

Comment: It is coding specific actually, he just didn't provide enough information for me to formulate a proper answer for him

Comment: @Syntle what information do you need?

Comment: I use discord v12

Comment: for the `role` argument, you want that to be a role mention or a role ID?

Comment: mentioned role @syntle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grab the users in the role and then loop through them and DM them:

```js
if (!args[0]) return message.reply('you need to provide a role')
if (!args[1]) return message.reply('you need to provide a message')
const role = message.mentions.roles.first()
message.guild.roles.cache.get(role.id).members.forEach(member => member.send(args[1]))
```