# How to send a message to all members who have a role from person with role, that have permission to use this cmd (discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm coding a bot using discord.js. I would like to send a `<message>` to all members who have `<role>` when person with role, that have permission to use command:

```
/send <role> <message>
```

in a channel.

How can I do this?

I copied and slightly remade this topic, because in the original one the answer was irrelevant at the moment

I tried a similar theme, but it is not relevant at the moment

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261942/how-to-send-a-message-to-all-members-who-have-a-role-discord-js)

Comment: 2 questions, would the message sent go to their dm's or to a channel in the guild, also is this to be a slash command (interaction) or a prefix command (message)?

Comment: I want to send a slash command in the text channel in discord guild and that according to the parameters entered by this command, people with the role receive a newsletter in dm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
const {
    SlashCommandBuilder
} = require('@discordjs/builders')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('newsletter')
        .setDescription('Send a message to members by role')
        .addRoleOption(option =>
            option
            .setName('role')
            .setDescription('What role')
            .setRequired(true))
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option
            .setName('message')
            .setDescription('What is the message.')
            .setRequired(true)),
    async execute(client, interaction) {
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('959899135258026055')
        const role2have = [
            '54654546545645656',
            '65465456465456465456'
        ]
        if (interaction.member.roles.cache.some(role => role2have.includes(role.id))) {
            const role = guild.roles.cache.get(interaction.options.getRole('role').id)
            console.log(role)
            role.members.forEach(member => {
                member.send({
                    content: `${interaction.options.getString('message')}`
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(`Unable to DM ${member.user.username} - received error:\n${err}`)
                })
            })
            return interaction.reply({
                content: 'Message sent',
                ephemeral: true
            })
        } else {
            return interaction.reply({
                content: 'You do not have permission to use this command',
                ephemeral: true
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This command is then executed:
`/newsletter role: @role message: message content`

Comment: /home/runner/<name>/index.js:40
    name: ‘newsletter’,
          
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

screenshot - https://imgur.com/a/t1A1hbJ

Comment: That means you use a different command handler than what I posted my answer in, can you provide a screenshot of another commands code